# accordion slide down brekaing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was doing some work to learn about jquery and other stuff in javascript, and at the same time, trying to build something new, in dashboard style, just for learn, but in the middle of this, I added an accordion, but its releasing other stuff that I don't want to, if you guys can take a look on my codepen project, I'll be greatful. The problem I'm looking for a solution is that the frame "Player Actions" are inheriting the same properties of "Strategy Analyzer", and when I slide down the "Resume" they do the same thing on the rest of the page.

I'm using this for the accordion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accordionContent').hide();
  $('.accordionTitle').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

The rest of the code, html, and css, are on the link.

[CodePen Project Here](https://codepen.io/rogersimps/pen/vXWqaN)

Thanks for all.

Comment: You need to set a height to '.frame', and then add the frame with an accordion open a 'max-height' maybe through a new class. or create 2 separate 'contentBody'

Comment: @Aschab But setting a height won't block the stretching of the frame?

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a new class to the second frame and it seems to work.

```
.nocollapse {
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Codepen [Demo](https://codepen.io/norcaljohnny/pen/rrYEEq)

Comment: But this looks the same, the 'Player Actions' are stretching with the Strategy Analyzer, what I need is keep the "player actions' with his own size, and resize the slide down/up only on 'strategy analyzer'. The content will be generated after, with a script, but I need to do it yet =)

Comment: Ah, i just noticed that wasnt expanding as well. So I just assumed thats what it was. Will look now.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: @RogerSimons can you vote this as the answer so it doesnt just sit. Cheers.